# How to add annotation in jfree line chart

Tags: java, charts, jfreechart

Im using jfree charts for my application. I need a chart with stroke point values appear above the x axis label.

**Expected**

[image]

And i need to remove the tick mark in between the values(54% and 2008).
I have tried the below code to get the annotation,

```
final DefaultCategoryDataset dataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();

        dataset.addValue(23, "Line", "2008");
        dataset.addValue(145, "Line", "2009");
        dataset.addValue(245, "Line", "2010");
        dataset.addValue(322, "Line", "2011");
        final JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createLineChart(
                "", // chart title
                "", // domain axis label
                "", // range axis label
                dataset, // data
                PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, // orientation
                false, // include legend
                false, // tooltips
                false // urls
                );

        chart.setBackgroundPaint(Color.WHITE);
        chart.setBorderVisible(true);
        chart.setBorderPaint(Color.decode("#EEEEEE"));
        chart.setPadding(new RectangleInsets(10, 10, 5, 5));

        final CategoryPlot plot = (CategoryPlot) chart.getPlot();
        plot.setBackgroundPaint(Color.WHITE);
        plot.setRangeZeroBaselinePaint(Color.RED);
        plot.setOutlineVisible(false);
        plot.setRangeGridlinePaint(Color.white);
        plot.setDomainGridlinePaint(Color.BLUE);        

        final CategoryAxis categoryAxis = (CategoryAxis) plot.getDomainAxis();
        categoryAxis.setAxisLineVisible(false);
        categoryAxis.setTickMarksVisible(false);
        categoryAxis.setTickLabelFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", java.awt.Font.PLAIN, 8));        
        
        final NumberAxis rangeAxis = (NumberAxis) plot.getRangeAxis();
        rangeAxis.setVisible(false);
        rangeAxis.setLabelPaint(Color.BLUE);
        rangeAxis.setRangeWithMargins(21, 600);

        DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("###,###");

        StandardCategoryItemLabelGenerator labelGenerator = new StandardCategoryItemLabelGenerator("{2}", format);
        final LineAndShapeRenderer renderer = (LineAndShapeRenderer) plot.getRenderer();
        renderer.setBaseShapesVisible(true);
        renderer.setBaseShapesFilled(true);
        renderer.setSeriesStroke(0, new BasicStroke(1.5f));
        renderer.setSeriesItemLabelsVisible(0, true);
        renderer.setBaseItemLabelGenerator(labelGenerator);
        renderer.setBaseItemLabelFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", java.awt.Font.PLAIN, 9));
        Shape circle = new Ellipse2D.Double(-2, -2, 4, 4);
        renderer.setSeriesShape(0, circle);        
        plot.getRenderer().setSeriesPaint(0, Color.decode("#0066CC"));        
        //       CategoryAnnotation categoryAnnotation=new CategoryLineAnnotation(Male1, 248, Male2, 216, null, null);
//        XYLineAnnotation annotation=new XYLineAnnotation(8, 0, 8, 24, new BasicStroke(2.0f), Color.blue);
//        plot.addAnnotation( (CategoryAnnotation) annotation);

        try {
            ChartUtilities.saveChartAsPNG(new File("E:\\jfreeLinechart.png"), chart, 290, 95);
            System.out.println("=====chart=====");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

from the above code im getting the following chart

**Actual**

[image]

Please help me to get the expected image in jfree line chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution. For the expected Chart you have to create the dummy series values. And use this code.

```
public String createLineChart() throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Line chart");
        final DefaultCategoryDataset dataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();

        dataset.addValue(14, "Line", "2008");
        dataset.addValue(18, "Line", "2009");
        dataset.addValue(22, "Line", "2010");

        dataset.addValue(13, "Line2", "2008");
        dataset.addValue(13, "Line2", "2009");
        dataset.addValue(13, "Line2", "2010");
        final JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createLineChart(
                "", // chart title
                "", // domain axis label
                "", // range axis label
                dataset, // data
                PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, // orientation
                false, // include legend
                false, // tooltips
                false // urls
        );

        chart.setBackgroundPaint(Color.WHITE);
        final CategoryPlot plot = (CategoryPlot) chart.getPlot();
        plot.setBackgroundPaint(Color.WHITE);
        plot.setRangeZeroBaselinePaint(Color.RED);
        plot.setOutlineVisible(false);
        plot.setRangeGridlinePaint(Color.white);
        plot.setDomainGridlinePaint(Color.BLUE);

        final CategoryAxis categoryAxis = (CategoryAxis) plot.getDomainAxis();
        categoryAxis.setAxisLineVisible(false);
        categoryAxis.setTickMarksVisible(false);
        categoryAxis.setMaximumCategoryLabelLines(2);

        final NumberAxis rangeAxis = (NumberAxis) plot.getRangeAxis();
        rangeAxis.setVisible(false);
        rangeAxis.setLabelPaint(Color.BLUE);
        rangeAxis.setRange(13, 23);
        rangeAxis.setTickUnit(new NumberTickUnit(20));

        final LineAndShapeRenderer renderer = (LineAndShapeRenderer) plot.getRenderer();
        renderer.setBaseShapesVisible(true);
        renderer.setBaseShapesFilled(true);
        renderer.setSeriesStroke(0, new BasicStroke(2.0f));
        renderer.setSeriesItemLabelsVisible(1, Boolean.TRUE);
        Shape circle = new Ellipse2D.Double(-3, -3, 6, 6);
        renderer.setSeriesShape(0, circle);
        renderer.setSeriesShape(1, null);
        renderer.setBaseItemLabelGenerator(new CustomLabelGenerator());
//        MyGenerator generator=new MyGenerator();
//        renderer.setSeriesItemLabelGenerator(1, generator);
        renderer.setBaseItemLabelsVisible(true);
        plot.getRenderer().setSeriesPaint(0, Color.decode("#0066CC"));
        plot.getRenderer().setSeriesPaint(1, Color.WHITE);

//        ValueAxis range = plot.getRangeAxis();
//        range.setUpperMargin(0.20);
        try {
            ChartUtilities.saveChartAsPNG(new File("/media/root/668ea9a3-d26c-4896-a2f0-756dfb532756/jfreeLinechart.png"), chart, 400, 200);
            System.out.println("=====chart=====");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Line chart :" + e);
        }
        xyLineChart();
        return "success";
    }

    static class CustomLabelGenerator extends AbstractCategoryItemLabelGenerator implements CategoryItemLabelGenerator {

            public CustomLabelGenerator() {
                super("", NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance());
            }

            public String generateLabel(CategoryDataset dataset, int series, int category) {

                String result = null;
                if (series == 1) {
                    series = 0;
                    Number value = dataset.getValue(series, category);
                    result = value.toString();
                    System.out.println("===========result===============" + series + "====category======" + category);
                }
                return result;
            }

            public String generateRowLabel(CategoryDataset arg0, int arg1) {
                return null;
            }

            public String generateColumnLabel(CategoryDataset arg0, int arg1) {
                return null;
            }
        }
```

You will get the appropriate chart...

Comment: It looks a good solution!!. It is very common to do this kind of things, using White colors or hiding/showing series with jfreechart

Answer (score 2):

Using the method `setBasePositiveItemLabelPosition` you can set the base positive item label position. Try this:

```
renderer.setBasePositiveItemLabelPosition(
                   new ItemLabelPosition(ItemLabelAnchor.OUTSIDE8, TextAnchor.CENTER));
```

Using `OUTSIDE`, `INSIDE`, or `CENTER` you can specify where the label will be placed respecting the item.

Comment: this doesnt works. The o/p of the above code is like my Actual output as shown above. But i need like my expected image

Comment: The position of the label is relative to the item so I think it is not possible to write them at the bottom of the chart and above the axis. You could try to concatenate the value of the item to the category value and try a break line with `categoryAxis.setMaximumCategoryLabelLines(2);` but it doesn't guarantee a good result

Comment: I have found an answer. Please refer it and suggest me if you found any mistake